# Give an expression of type ('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> ('a * 'a -> 'a) in Ocaml

Tags: types, expression, ocaml

I'm learning Ocaml and i've come through this question in a test :

Give an expression of type `('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> ('a * 'a -> 'a)`

I can't get the solution, the closest i can get is :

```
let expr f (x, y) = if f x y = x then x else y
val expr : ('a -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'a * 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

If you have an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the only missing piece is to recognize that these types are the same:

```
a -> b -> c
a -> (b -> c)
```

In a type expression, the `->` operator is right associative.

In other words, it looks to me like your answer is already correct.